# Nested Callback stuck in Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have nested callback that is setup as following:

```
function submitForm() {
  BuildContent($('#Content').val(), '', true, submitForm)   
  PerformSubmit();
}

function BuildContent(textWithUrl, textSource, isSubmit, callback) {
  console.log("GetWebContent in Progress");
  GetWebContent(sendurls, BuildContent)
  console.log("GetWebContent done");
  callback();
}

function GetWebContent(content, callback) {
  $.ajax({....
    sucess:function(msg) { .....
      callback();
  }
```

}

**expected outcome** is when submitForm is called  it calls Build Conetent which calls GetWebContent. o**nly after the ajax call in  inside GetWebContent is sucessfull then only PerformSubmit(); is executed.** for some reason it loops and JS hangs and becomes unresponsive and BuildContent console logs keeps prininting in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a misunderstanding of how callbacks work. When a callback returns, it does not resume execution where it left off. The function calling the callback finishes immediately.

You need to structure the code like so:

```
function submitForm(){
    BuildContent($('#content').val(), '', true, performSubmit);
}

function BuildContent(textWithUrl, textSource, isSubmit, callback){
    console.log("GetWebContent in Progress");
    GetWebContent(sendurls, callback);
}

function GetWebContent(content,callback){
    $.ajax({...
        success:function(msg){ ....
            console.log("GetWebContent done");
            callback(); <-- performSubmit is being called here, 
                        after all of the asynchronous work is done
        }
    });
}
```

You'll notice that I pass the performSubmit along as the callback to each of these functions, and then call it in the success function.

Anything AFTER the GetWebContent call within BuildContent will execute immediately, so you can't expect the second call to console.log to be AFTER the ajax request is finished.

Answer (score 1):

The `BuildContent` callback called just after the console.log is the function `submitForm` 
which promptly calls `BuildContent` hence an endless loop.

Without doing an in-depth analysis, I would suggest removing the call `callback` at the end of `BuildContent` and passing it instead as the second parameter of the call to `GetWebContent`.

After a bit more thought, in `submitForm` teh callback you send to `BuildContent` should be `PerformSubmit`. My alterations to `buldContent` stand.